# Looping over a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

results = pd.DataFrame()
BTC = pd.read_csv('BTC_USDT_Range100.csv', index_col=0)
BTC['Standard Returns'] = np.log(BTC['Close'] / BTC['Close'].shift())
for a in range(5, 250):
    BTC['SMA1'] = BTC['Close'].rolling(a).mean()
    BTC['SMA2'] = BTC['Close'].rolling(300).mean()
    BTC['Position'] = np.where(BTC['SMA1'] > BTC['SMA2'], 1, 0)
    BTC.dropna(inplace = True)
    BTC.index = np.arange(0, len(BTC))
    BTC['Strategy'] = BTC['Position'].shift(1)*BTC['Standard Returns']
    print(a, BTC['Strategy'].sum())
```

but the results don't seem to work out as they should. For example, running the above, after a = 171 all of the BTC['Strategy'].sum() values are zero, however if you run the chunk of code inside the for loop for just the value a=172 it gives 0.71.

The values seem to be decreasing in value as the loop goes on until they are "essentially zero", so I feel I am iterating over this DataFrame wrong and it isn't "resetting" the columns of the DataFrame inside the for loop properly.

EDIT: As a sample, I supply here BTC.head(50):

```
        Timestamp     Open     High      Low    Close      Volume
0   1577836800000  7195.24  7196.25  7178.64  7179.78   95.509133
1   1577837100000  7179.76  7191.77  7178.20  7191.07   59.365225
2   1577837400000  7193.15  7193.53  7180.24  7180.97   48.068510
3   1577837700000  7180.97  7186.40  7177.35  7178.29   32.192929
4   1577838000000  7177.71  7182.46  7175.47  7176.96   49.027397
5   1577838300000  7177.59  7185.56  7176.11  7178.45   47.022328
6   1577838600000  7178.19  7185.44  7177.54  7180.68   35.109830
7   1577838900000  7180.96  7182.53  7176.23  7177.53   24.863496
8   1577839200000  7177.14  7182.45  7176.34  7179.56   23.514132
9   1577839500000  7179.35  7182.99  7179.35  7182.94   21.358850
10  1577839800000  7182.94  7183.98  7175.51  7179.03   42.910971
11  1577840100000  7178.65  7181.75  7175.46  7177.02   32.872100
12  1577840400000  7176.47  7185.86  7175.71  7183.29   30.163076
13  1577840700000  7183.55  7194.04  7182.82  7189.62   44.803327
14  1577841000000  7189.63  7194.04  7188.62  7190.86   28.554119
15  1577841300000  7190.46  7194.27  7189.23  7194.06   24.216078
16  1577841600000  7193.02  7198.00  7190.79  7192.39   34.107575
17  1577841900000  7193.01  7217.00  7191.98  7212.10  193.219399
18  1577842200000  7212.10  7230.00  7211.32  7218.83  273.468070
19  1577842500000  7219.11  7221.95  7210.53  7216.00   60.977766
20  1577842800000  7216.02  7219.11  7207.17  7211.87   52.801416
21  1577843100000  7212.34  7212.67  7205.01  7205.08   47.987055
22  1577843400000  7205.08  7211.77  7204.28  7209.35   54.491792
23  1577843700000  7209.75  7216.41  7207.39  7216.27   38.262930
24  1577844000000  7215.52  7223.37  7214.09  7217.25   62.727497
25  1577844300000  7217.21  7223.80  7214.27  7217.18   40.379270
26  1577844600000  7217.73  7219.03  7211.41  7211.97   30.653886
27  1577844900000  7212.87  7225.00  7212.15  7224.20   32.415222
28  1577845200000  7224.20  7230.00  7218.97  7229.32   36.710927
29  1577845500000  7229.50  7238.88  7224.91  7228.09  106.131355
30  1577845800000  7227.12  7236.07  7226.79  7234.76   56.688336
31  1577846100000  7233.83  7235.83  7228.08  7232.21   73.997180
32  1577846400000  7232.75  7237.99  7229.65  7237.63   42.633819
33  1577846700000  7237.42  7237.81  7231.93  7236.13   38.429914
34  1577847000000  7237.21  7244.20  7232.20  7243.65   89.949170
35  1577847300000  7243.07  7244.87  7238.00  7242.85   44.440233
36  1577847600000  7242.66  7245.00  7230.25  7235.33   87.259123
37  1577847900000  7235.18  7235.66  7220.10  7224.98  108.385003
38  1577848200000  7224.98  7229.70  7223.43  7228.50   75.378899
39  1577848500000  7227.43  7235.50  7227.19  7235.50   76.264249
40  1577848800000  7234.11  7237.41  7232.87  7235.87   33.335067
41  1577849100000  7235.53  7238.77  7231.23  7237.15   59.789927
42  1577849400000  7237.82  7244.33  7237.16  7243.77   60.043500
43  1577849700000  7242.40  7242.48  7226.00  7228.85   81.881714
44  1577850000000  7228.75  7231.99  7220.23  7221.27   61.273717
45  1577850300000  7221.27  7227.89  7220.00  7227.50   38.460440
46  1577850600000  7228.18  7228.18  7223.21  7226.06   45.602554
47  1577850900000  7225.58  7230.78  7223.61  7225.01   56.050674
48  1577851200000  7225.00  7229.72  7223.93  7228.58   64.682238
49  1577851500000  7228.09  7229.88  7224.61  7228.14   36.798454
```

and the code can be altered to produce the problem:

```
BTC['Standard Returns'] = np.log(BTC['Close'] / BTC['Close'].shift())
for a in range(5, 15):
    BTC['SMA1'] = BTC['Close'].rolling(a).mean()
    BTC['SMA2'] = BTC['Close'].rolling(20).mean()
    BTC['Position'] = np.where(BTC['SMA1'] > BTC['SMA2'], 1, 0)
    BTC.dropna(inplace = True)
    BTC.index = np.arange(0, len(BTC))
    BTC['Strategy'] = BTC['Position'].shift(1)*BTC['Standard Returns']
    print(a, BTC['Strategy'].sum())
```

which then returns all zeroes after a=7.

Comment: please add a sample dataset in a way that can be reproduced with code..

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo Okay, all done - I have adapted the code to produce the same problem on a smaller dataset also

Comment: the column names are missing my bro, also ideally I should be able to copy paste to recreate the dataframe.

Comment: Sorry @FrancoPiccolo they were cut off! Is that better?